# Bootstrap pop up message

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a pop up message using bootstrap but I am stuck and have no idea what I am doing wrong. I would be greatful if someone could help me out.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreinfo">Find out more</button>

<div id="moreinfo" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        fds
      </div>
      <!--end of modal header-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        fds
      </div>
      <!--end of modal content-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        fds
      </div>
      <!--end of modal footer-->
    </div>
    <!--end of modal content-->
  </div>
  <!--end of modal dialog-->
</div>
<!--en dof more info div-->
```

Thats my code

Thanks

Comment: Where is your CSS? - it can also be helpful to supply a jsfiddle

Comment: remove space & add dash(-) for class="modal dialog" to class="modal-dialog"

Answer (score 2):

You just miss slept a class name `class="modal-dialog"`

Answer (score 0):

You missed '-' in class name `modal dilog` --> `modal-dilog`

You can follow following code :

Find out more

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
            fds
            </div><!--end of modal header-->

            <div class="modal-content">
            fds
            </div><!--end of modal content-->

            <div class="modal-footer">
            fds
            </div><!--end of modal footer-->

        </div><!--end of modal content-->

    </div><!--end of modal dialog-->

</div><!--en dof more info div-->
```